# Add to an array being read/deleted from in an interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval

What are the best practices for adding an object to a javascript array while it is currently in use in an interval method?

```
function someEvent()
{
    array.push("something");
}

function update()
{
    array.forEach(function(o, i, a))
    {
       // do something with the object and delete it 
    });
}

var updateInterval = setInterval(update, 1000);
```

This is used in Angular context.
I know there are some things in Javascript like calling a function will never call that function before the other function has finished, what applies to interval and the use of arrays like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying data that `setInterval` is using won't cause any problems, for the reasons you specified. Because of JavaScript's single-threaded nature. Setinterval creates the illusion of concurrency, but if other code is running it goes into a queue, so there won't be any threading errors.

So even if we don't know whether for instance a click handler or a setInterval handler will be called *first*, we can guarantee that they will not be called *concurrently*.

See more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734047/2234742).